# What does "writing of a new patron" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This was from the introduction of the translation of "The Prince" written by Niccolo Machiavelli.

The intro tackled Machiavelli's letter to his son, Guido.

The letter read "'...I hope to make a good man of  you if you are willing to do your share.’ ***Then, writing of a new patron***, he continues: ‘This will turn out well for you,  but it is necessary for you to study..."

Comment: It says _**of** a patron (about a patron)_ not _of a new patron_.

Comment: @fev, it read "of a new patron" in the book. I've accidentally omitted it. My bad. I've fixed it.

Comment: There is still no mystery about "writing of/about someone"...

Comment: @fev in the text, it appears so that the writer wants to point out that Machiavelli is doing something. Besides, if it's a literal patron, I'm clearly lost as I do not know who the writer is talking about.

Comment: You know that "of" means "about" ([sense 5a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of), example "stories of her travels")? Are you asking who the patron is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those times, a man or woman could often only prosper and advance their station in life if they were supported, encouraged, paid and helped by a patron.

Even today the meaning is still:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/patron)
> *patron*
> a person or group that supports an activity or organization, especially by giving money

A fuller account more relevant to late mediaeval times may be found:

> [Wiley Online Library](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781118396957.wbemlb108)
> The system of patronage was one of the most significant social and cultural structures in the Middle Ages. The relationships forged between patrons and their clients were based not only on financial support, but also political and personal influence. Men and women from a wide variety of social backgrounds participated in the patronage system; their important contributions to this system included endowing medieval colleges, commissioning individual translations or artworks, and supporting writers and artists for many years.

With this in mind, you may see that Machiavelli is writing about a new patron$ from whom benefits derive.

Finding a patron is clearly a good and advantageous thing ("will turn out well") but Machiavelli advises Guido to benefit from patronage by studying, or to study so as to merit and benefit from patronage. It is not clear from the text which of these is intended.

$ I have looked at the full (English) text and it is not clear if the patron is Machiavelli's or Guido's. This does not affect the main answer.